# How are MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH intents tested in Google Assistant inside the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-emulator

I'm trying to debug why using the Android emulator cannot launch my app via a search intent when run via Google Assistant.

I've implemented MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH as an `intent-filter` and have it wired to an Activity. I added a breakpoint to the activity to see how it is invoked.

If I search through the Android search bar...

[image: search for a song]

All I get are web results:

[image: web results]

How do I get search to invoke my app via the emulator?

I can also get intents to invoke my app fine using adb:

```
am start -a "android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" -e query "yellow\ submarine"
```

This invokes my app as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason was my query was incorrect. I should have typed:

> play rick astley

Not:

> play *a song by* rick astley

The list of commands are here: https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7030379?hl=en

However, for development purposes I found it easier to use `adb`:

```
adb [-s emulator-device-id] shell am start -a android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH -e query "rick\ astley"
```